# Autolayout: Abnormal Behavior : View not resizing on 3.5 inch screen

Tags: ios

There's nothing special going on in this view, but I cannot seem to get Autolayout to play nicely! Please see the images below. I have tried so many variations and still end up all broken. I pretty much refuse to turn off autolayout due to the fact that the struts and springs are just being translated into constraints at which tells me there must be a way and I'm just doing it wrong.

**4 inch CORRECT Display**

([image: http://i.imgur.com/uGjsO4Yl.png])

**3.5 inch with "bottom space to bottom layout" for workout button. Vertical spacing in-between all.  The button comes up but nothing shrinks and the "next day/last day" view gets bumped.**

([image: http://i.imgur.com/QH41Sc0l.png])

Comment: The "next day/last day" view shouldn't do that if it has vertical spacing constraints to the workout button and the round view (Whatever that is) above it. Does it have those? Which items can shrink? Do you have height constraints on some of the items?

Comment: @rdelmar **Constraints for what you see in 3.5 from the top down**   

**1.** Vertical Space - (12) - Progress Spinner View - Current Week Day Level View **2.** Vertical Space - (8) - Next Day Last Day View - Progress Spinner View **3.** Vertical Space - (8) - Button - Workout - Next Day Last Day View **4.** Vertical Space - (64) - Bottom Layout Guide - Button - Workout

No height constraints specified. I'm ok if it shrinks all the views and subviews!

Comment: Those aren't enough constraints to have unambiguous constraints, unless all the views have an intrinsic content size (and if they don't the system may be adding fixed size constraints for you). What kind of view is the "progress spinner view"?

Comment: @rdelmar The 'progress spinner view' is a STKSpinnerView (github.com/joeconwaystk/STKSpinnerView) UIView subclass with an added UIImageView subview. So it seems as if I need to set more constraints even for portrait only view modes? The height and width for all views were just set in the Storyboard, not hard-coded programmatically.